# JAWS not reading AccessibilityDescriptionfor a button

Tags: winforms, accessibility, screen-readers

I have a number of buttons on a WinForms User Control. I have given each button an AccessibilityName and an AccessibilityDescription. JAWS will read the AccessibilityName however doesn't read the description even if I press [INSERT+B]. I'm unsure why this is happening or if I need to set the AccessibilityRole.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> At the time of writing this, attempts to expose supplemental
> information through the Button.AccessibleDescription property
> typically do not work. This is because the AccessibleDescription
> string value does not get exposed through the UIA properties that are
> commonly used for supplemental information, (for example, the UIA
> FullDescription or HelpText properties).
>
> Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/accessibility-tools-docs/items/WinForms/Button_HelpText

The linked page suggests using `Button.QueryAccessibilityHelp` event handler.

I am not sure but [this bug fix may be relevant](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/pull/3215), but I am not familiar enough with WinForms accessibility to know if this is the same issue.